# Why doesn't SLES 10.3 has /dev/shm?

Tags: sles

It's strange that on all of our Linux systems there is a separated filesystem: /dev/shm. But there isn't any on SLES 10.3 machines, because it's just a directory on them.

**My question:** Can someone provide an offical source what states that SLES 10.3 doesn't use a separated /dev/shm?

Answer (score 0):

SLES 10 SP4:

```
$ mount | grep tmpfs
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw)
```

Not sure about SP3, but I would expect it to be similar.What other systems are you comparing SLES 10 SP3 to? It's rather old and things have changed over the years...

Comment: RHEL5; SLES 9; SLES 11

Comment: OK. Why are you actually missing it? `/dev/shm` is in `tmpfs` anyway in this setup.

Comment: Looks like all other distros have it as separated FS & it would be useful if we would have it separated on SLES 10 too, but we don't know why isn't it by default there..

Comment: From the practical point of view - why just not modify `/etc/fstab` accordingly?